# Modify "Link" field using Powershell

Tags: 2010, powershell

How do I change both the URL and description of a "Link" field using a Powershell script?

In the past I've used the following:

```
$newitem = $splist.Items.Add()
$newitem["Title"] = $somestuff
```

Comment: I've found the answer: the url stored like a simple string with url, description divided by comma.

Comment: I think Mike beat you to it. Please mark his answer as solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending your example above:

```
$newitem = $splist.Items.Add()
$somestuff = "http://www.google.com, Google"
$newitem["Link"] = $somestuff
```

That will, assuming "Link" is a type of "Hyperlink or Picture" (Hyperlink), create a link that says Google and links to http://www.google.com